# If I knew where she <lived><lives> now, I'd go and see her

Tags: tense, conditional-constructions, subordinate-clauses

(1) If I knew where she **lived** now, I'd go and see her.

(2) If I knew where she **lives** now, I'd go and see her.

[Question] Which is correct?

I think that (1) is correct, but a Japanese teacher of English says that only (2) is correct because of "now." I am confused.

I have never learned about what tense should be used in a subordinate clause of an if-clause of a second conditional sentence.

Thank you.

[Edit] FumbleFinger's suggested question [tense in a sub-clause](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/102108/tense-in-a-sub-clause)

is about sentences in the indicative mood, but my sentences are in the subjunctive mood.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I asked if she knew French.(I asked if she knows French)](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/329932/i-asked-if-she-knew-french-i-asked-if-she-knows-french)

Comment: Both your examples are fine, but *usually*, native speakers "backshift" the verb in the complement *(**lived**)* to match the main verb *(**knew**)*. This doesn't normally make any difference to the meaning, and I don't think it's relevant [whether or not ***now*** is explicitly included](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=asked+where+he+lived+now&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) (it's always ***implicit*** in  such contexts, anyway).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't think 'lived'+'now' is correct because 'lived now' itself doesn't correspond.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think the point of 'now' could be dangled with the full if-clause and in that case, the first sentence is fine according to your comment. I respect your comment NOW.

Comment: @Kaguyahime If the 'now' modifies 'knew', then I think the first sentence is also fine as already Fumble explained. Plz refer to this: What would he say if he were with me now?

Comment: @gomadeng: I think you're misunderstanding what's going on here. The cited example #1 is typical "backshifting" - in a context where native speakers *usually* backshift. But it's got nothing to do with "now" modifying ***to know*** as opposed to ***to live***. Both OP's examples mean exactly the same thing. Because of the word "now" you can't "contrive" a possible different meaning based on the idea that she might no longer live there. It's not like *She said her name **was** Miss Smith* (before she married Mr ***Jones***, and changed her name).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [tense in a sub-clause](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/102108/tense-in-a-sub-clause)

Comment: @FumbleFingers 'where she lived now' is a noun clause but if 'now' modifies 'knew', it(now) becomes separate, functioning as an adverb; logically speaking 'where she lived now' as a chunk is viewed as 'disagreement' in terms of tense vs. time adverb; we never say 'I lived in NY now'.

Answer (score 1):

Your teacher is wrong.

The first sentence with "lived" is correct and much more natural than the second. The simple past form "lived" is correct because this sentence is in the *irrealis mood* (usually called "unreal grammar" in ESL material). In the *irrealis mood*, some verbs **must** shift to the relatively past form, in this case "*know --> knew*" and "*will --> would*", and other verbs *may optionally* shift to the past form, possibly including "lives/lived" in our case here.

The second sentence may be technically correct, but few native speakers would choose "lives" over "lived".

While the word "now" modifies "lives/lived", "lived" is still correct because that form represents the *irrealis mood*, not the *simple past time*. The verb "lived" is very much *in the present time*, not the past, so "now" and "lived" do not contradict each other.

Comment: Personally, I think I'd still use ***lived*** in example #2 regardless of the presence or absence of the word ***now***. The possibility of me using ***lives*** might rise significantly if I was placing very heavy stress on ***now***. (But that's one of those contexts where I struggle to know what I would *actually* say, if I've been thinking about it too long! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Agreed. I'm not confident whether the second sentence is ever correct, so I left that possibility open in my wording. I think the bottom line here is that the teacher incorrectly believed that "lived" indicated a past time, which is incompatible with "now".

Comment: It seems a bit extreme to suggest OP's #2 *(**lives**)* is *never* "correct", but it's certainly rarely if ever *idiomatic*. Google Books has just a handful of written instances of *if I knew what it **is***, as compared to dozens if not hundreds with *...what it **was.*** Maybe it's precisely *because* it seems so easy to "justify" Present Tense if those words are followed by ***now*** that we don't like to completely rule it out. As a native speaker I just know I really don't like it, but being a non-native Anglophone, OP's cited teacher doesn't have that "built-in reality check".

Answer (score 0):

> If I knew where she lived/lives now, I'd go and see her.

The verb 'knew' in the if-clause is a past tense, which means you don't know the place where she **lives** at the time of speaking.

The 'would' in the 'I'd' is also in the 'past form' of 'will'. which implies that the main clause — I'd go and see her — is under the influence of 'if-clause'.

You example senence is a typical of a subjunctive mood 'past' which means:

As I **don't** know where she lives, I **can't** go and see her.

The noun-cluase — where she lives — is natural with or without the adverb 'now'.

'If I had known where she lived then('now' is incorrect), I'd have gone and seen her.' means:

You didn't know in the past where she lived and couldn't go and see her.

Grammatically 'lived'+'now' is incorrrect in terms of tense agreement though 'just now' implies 'a moment ago' and goes well with the 'past form' of the verbs.

EDIT: Though 'lived now' is incorrect, your two examples are correct because the 'now' modifies the verb 'knew' and your examples are subjunctive mood.

PS. My previous answer (before edit) was focused on only 'lived now' which is included in 'where he lived now'.

Comment: For what it''s worth, Google Books has 17 instances of the supposedly "incorrect" form [*If I knew where he **was** now*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22If+I+knew+where+he+was+now%22), but only 10 of [*If I knew where he **is** now*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22If+I+knew+where+he+is+now%22). Half of which are duplicates of the happenstance collocation *I would also send a copy to our friend Story, if I knew where he is , **- now I must revert to what perplexes me***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers In "If I knew sth now", it's clear that 'now' modifies 'If I knew sth', especially 'knew', this is grammatical due to the fact that the if-clause is a subjunctive mood(past) that is used to describe a present situation the other way round: As I don't know sth now, s + v (past verb like would/could)—in this case 'would' is used instead of 'will'. This means he doesn't know "currently" where he lives. If backshifting(where he LIVED) is used, then the 'now' should modify 'knew'. You should keep in mind that the core element is if i KNEW sth NOW (subjunctive past)

Comment: How does all that explain why you say *Grammatically 'lived'+'now' is incorrect*, whereas Google Books clearly shows ***was + now*** is far more common than ***is + now***?

Comment: @FumbleFingers The 'now' is an adverb and it modifies the subjunctive mood verb 'knew': the 'now' should be excluded from 'where he + v'.

Comment: That's as may be. But your answer seems to be saying the most common form used ***in writing*** (and probably even more so in natural speech) is "incorrect". How can the majority of native speakers be wrong?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I edited the answer (added EDIT part). 'lived now' is incorrect and only correct if the 'now' modifies the subjunctive mood verb 'knew'.

Comment: I still think you're wrong. In OP's context it would be perverse to understand ***now*** as modifying ***knew*** (i.e. - equivant to the alternative phrasing *If I **now knew** where she lived/lives*). In almost every case where this construction arises, the (usually backshifted) verb in the subordinate clause (***lived/lives***, here) would be the target of any time-based adverbial such as ***now*** (or ***then***, or whatever).

Comment: @FumbleFingers 'SUBJUNCTIVE MOOD' is NOT RESTRICTED to 'TENSE'. That's why I persistently keep arguing the 'now' modifies 'knew' and has NO problem.

Comment: None of that answers my question *how does this explain why you say Grammatically 'lived'+'now' is incorrect*, given the evidence is that's what people usually say/write. But this doesn't seem to be getting us anywhere.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146359/discussion-between-gomadeng-and-fumblefingers).